# Receive async exception directly

Tags: c++, asynchronous, c++17, try-catch

```
class ClassA
{
    void running()
    {
        int count = 0;

        m_worker_stop.store(true);
        while (m_worker_stop.load() == false)
        {
            count++;
            if (count == 10)
            {
                // Make exception
                std::vector v(100000000000);
            }            
        }
    }

    void start()
    {
        m_worker = std::async(std::launch::async, &ClassA::running, this);
    }

    void stop()
    {
        m_worker_stop.store(true);
        if (m_worker.valid())
            m_worker.get();    // catch exception in this point
    }

    std::future<void>   m_worker;
    std::atomic_bool    m_worker_stop = { false };
}

class Main    // this is single-ton Main class
{
    ...
    void running()
    {
        try {
            m_classA->start();

            // Wait for external signal(ex. SIGINT, SIGTERM, ..)
            while (true) { // signal check }

            m_classA->stop();
        }
        catch(std::exception& e) {
            // re-create throwed object
        }
        catch(...) {
            // re-create throwed object
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    Manager::getInstance()::running();
    return 0;
}
```

Hello, everyone.
The approximate structure of the program is as above.

In fact, I have not only classA but also many other objects such as B, C, and D.
(start() and stop() function is simillar !)

An exception was raised using **std::vector v(1000000..)**

However, it became a catch when stop() was activated.

What I actually want is to delete the classA object and re-create it if an exception occurs.

So I need to catch directly when exception was occured.

In this case, is any idea to get exception without wait for signals?

Comment: It's unclear how this code ever gets to the `vector` definition where you (theoretically) throw the exception. The flag is only set to false when you first create the object. `running` never sets it to false, nor does anything else. So the loop in `running` should exit immediately. Even ignoring that, it's not really clear what this code is trying to do. What is `classA` supposed to represent? Why do you want the same object on both sides of an asychronous operation? The whole point of `promise`/`future` is that they're *not* like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of achieving the effect you want:

```
class Main    // this is single-ton Main class
{
    ...
    void running()
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < max_tries; ++i)
        {
            try {
                m_classA->start();
                    // Wait for external signal(ex. SIGINT, SIGTERM, ..)
                while (true) { 
                   // signal check ...
                }
                m_classA->stop();

                // path to happy ending :)
                LOG("Main::running(): Operation successful.", 
                return;
            }
            catch(std::exception& e) {
                LOG("Main::running(): Exception caught: message:\"{}\"", e.what());
            }
            catch(...) {
                LOG("Main::running(): Unspecified exception caught, aborting.");
                return;  // Example of 'unrecoverable error'
            }
        
            // this part is only executed after an exception.
            m_classA->shut_down();   // if you need some special shut down after an error.
            m_classA.clear();        // this is redundant, but explicit (optional)
            m_classA = MakeMeAnA();  // call our favorite A construction method.
        }

        // path to total failure :(
        LOG("Main::running(): Exiting after {} failed attempts", max_tries);
    }

  private:
      static constexpr size_t max_tries = 3;
};
```